# Avalonia Error on browser project start: Don't know how to detect app exit event for Avalonia.BrowserSingleViewLifetime

Tags: c#, .net, avaloniaui, avalonia

community. I'm trying to implement **data persistence** by using next guide from official documentation:

https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/next/concepts/reactiveui/data-persistence

I try to implement state persistence for both **browser and desktop**. If-else construction used for adopt different MVVM implementations of these key types of environments.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        AvaloniaXamlLoader.Load(this);
    }

    public override void OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted()
    {
        IStateStorage<MainViewModel> stateStorage = ApplicationLifetime is IClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetime
            ? new LocalFileStateStorage<MainViewModel>("appstate.json")
            : new WebApiStateStorage<MainViewModel>("http://localhost:5173/ClientState");

        var suspensionDriver = new DefaultSuspensionDriver<MainViewModel>(stateStorage);

        var suspension = new AutoSuspendHelper(ApplicationLifetime);
        RxApp.SuspensionHost.CreateNewAppState = () => new MainViewModel();
        RxApp.SuspensionHost.SetupDefaultSuspendResume(suspensionDriver);
        suspension.OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted();

        // Load the saved view model state.
        var state = RxApp.SuspensionHost.GetAppState<MainViewModel>();

        if (ApplicationLifetime is IClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetime desktop)
        {
            desktop.MainWindow = new MainWindow
            {
                DataContext = state
            };
            desktop.MainWindow.Show();
        }
        else if (ApplicationLifetime is ISingleViewApplicationLifetime singleViewPlatform)
        {
            singleViewPlatform.MainView = new MainView
            {
                DataContext = state
            };
        }

        base.OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted();
    }
```

But as a result of running this code in browser I got error:

> Don't know how to detect app exit event for
> Avalonia.BrowserSingleViewLifetime.

Does somebody know how to fix it and make browser load and save the `ViewModel` state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avalonia community helped me and gave a hint, that when you close browser tab - it 'just closes', without event and ability to handle it. After living some time with this information, I decided to dig into Avalonia sources and found next code of `AutoSuspendHelper` constructor:

```
    public AutoSuspendHelper(IApplicationLifetime lifetime)
    {
        RxApp.SuspensionHost.IsResuming = Observable.Never<Unit>();
        RxApp.SuspensionHost.IsLaunchingNew = _isLaunchingNew;

        if (Avalonia.Controls.Design.IsDesignMode)
        {
            this.Log().Debug("Design mode detected. AutoSuspendHelper won't persist app state.");
            RxApp.SuspensionHost.ShouldPersistState = Observable.Never<IDisposable>();
        }
        else if (lifetime is IControlledApplicationLifetime controlled)
        {
            this.Log().Debug("Using IControlledApplicationLifetime events to handle app exit.");
            controlled.Exit += (sender, args) => OnControlledApplicationLifetimeExit();
            RxApp.SuspensionHost.ShouldPersistState = _shouldPersistState;
        }
        else if (lifetime != null)
        {
            var type = lifetime.GetType().FullName;
            var message = $"Don't know how to detect app exit event for {type}."; // Here exception throws!
            throw new NotSupportedException(message);
        }
        else
        {
            var message = "ApplicationLifetime is null. "
                        + "Ensure you are initializing AutoSuspendHelper "
                        + "after Avalonia application initialization is completed.";
            throw new ArgumentNullException(message);
        }
        
        var errored = new Subject<Unit>();
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (o, e) => errored.OnNext(Unit.Default);
        RxApp.SuspensionHost.ShouldInvalidateState = errored;
    }
```

Discovering interfaces hierarchy, I found that community gave absolutely correct hint, and decided to rewrite my `App` class for at least loading of the state from my **WebApi** server with thoughts to implement some manual state saving in future:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        AvaloniaXamlLoader.Load(this);
    }

    public override void OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted()
    {
        IStateStorage<MainViewModel> stateStorage = ApplicationLifetime is IClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetime
            ? new LocalFileStateStorage<MainViewModel>("appstate.json")
            : new WebApiStateStorage<MainViewModel>("http://localhost:5173/ClientState");

        if (ApplicationLifetime is IClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetime desktop)
        {
            // now this code 
            var suspensionDriver = new DefaultSuspensionDriver<MainViewModel>(stateStorage);

            var suspension = new AutoSuspendHelper(ApplicationLifetime);
            RxApp.SuspensionHost.CreateNewAppState = () => new MainViewModel();
            RxApp.SuspensionHost.SetupDefaultSuspendResume(suspensionDriver);
            suspension.OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted();

            // Load the saved view model state.
            var state = RxApp.SuspensionHost.GetAppState<MainViewModel>();

            desktop.MainWindow = new MainWindow
            {
                DataContext = state
            };
            desktop.MainWindow.Show();
        }
        else if (ApplicationLifetime is ISingleViewApplicationLifetime singleViewPlatform)
        {
            var state = stateStorage.Load();

            singleViewPlatform.MainView = new MainView
            {
                DataContext = state
            };
        }

        base.OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted();
    }
}
```

Conclusion I made is better to **Ctrl+click** on method with exception than immediately try to google it (for such young framework there is very small knowledge base).